context_prompt in index.asChatengine not taking instructions
I used the exaxct example from llamaindex from here :
https://docs.llamaindex.ai/en/stable/examples/chat_engine/chat_engine_condense_plus_context/
Now if i want to add some instructions in context_prompt, it doesnt work perfectly ,
But if i put the same instruction in the query , it Works as expected
screenshot attached,
Any idea what am i missing

